# Using file_get_contents And Changing Domain of Links on the Included Page?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

On my page I have this piece of code:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.nbc.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

It includes the NBC website perfectly, but I notice that all of the links on the NBC.com website start with my domain name instead of http://nbc.com so they don't work.

So for example instead of http://nbc.com/the-blacklist/episodes being displayed on http://nbc.com website, its displaying http://my-domain.com/the-blacklist/episodes.

Is there any way to use `file_get_contents` do include a page into my URL, but make sure all the links on the page are the original links so they work fine?

Answer (score 1):

The links inside of pages you are pulling are using relative links (/page.html) instead of the full URL, you will need to do a Regex on the variable or string replace. To test it out you could do the following:

```
$domain = 'http://www.nbc.com';
$pull = file_get_contents($domain);
echo str_replace('href="/', 'href="' . $domain . '/', $pull);
```